# Automate captcha using Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am performing automation testing of a web application platform using Robot Framework (selenium2library) and could'nt find a way to automate the captcha field. Can someone give me some info. on how to identify and test this captcha field?

Thank you

Comment: I think the entire idea of CAPTCHA is to be impossible to automate

Comment: If you control both ends of the test, use some known challenges and solutions inside the test harness.

Answer (score 0):

Captcha is designed to be not automatible. The solution is to turn off captcha in your system under test. If you need to spefically test the captcha mechanism, you can do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Library CaptchaLibrary for your query. But this will only work if captcha is not striped.